# Arm T32 DAP: Debug Port Fail CTRLSTAT

Tags: arm

While attaching T32 to Arm cortex processors, it shows

```
DAP: Debug Port Fail CTRLSTAT = some 32 bit value.
```

How to debug the issue in this case? Has anybody came across this kind of error?

Comment: What is T32? A slightly more verbose question will get a much better response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The message is telling you that the debug port is not responding as expected. If you're using Serial Wire, it can indicate several possible error conditions. In the absence of any better information, maybe your debug connection speed is too high, or there is too much electro-magnetic interference.

In effect, your debug tool is unable to react to the behaviour of the target, at the low-level interface protocol. This register is described, for example, [here](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.100572_0000_00_en/Chunk54224660.html#ric1455619490503).